# Не работает русский язык в консоли

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <locale>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <conio.h>
 using namespace std;

int main()
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
double R, h, answ;
const double PI = 3.14159265;
cout << "Enter R" << endl;
cin >> R;
cout << "Enter h" << endl;
    cin >> h;
    answ = 2 * R*h*PI;
    cout << "R= " << R << "h= " << h << " Площадь поверхности цилиндра: " << 
    answ << endl;
    _getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `system("chcp 1251");` должно помочь.

Comment: Эту строку надо добавить сразу после int main()?
если да, то не помогает. Просто в консоли появилась строка "Active code page 1251", а русские буквы в виде вопросов как и были

Comment: `#include <iostream>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <conio.h>
 using namespace std;

int main() {
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("cls");

    double R, h, answ;
    const double PI = 3.14159265;
    cout << "Enter R" << endl;
    cin >> R;
    cout << "Enter h" << endl;
    cin >> h;
    answ = 2 * R*h*PI;
    cout << "R= " << R << "h= " << h << " Площадь поверхности цилиндра: " <<
    answ << endl;
    _getch();
    return(0);
}`

Comment: попробуй этот код.

Comment: Все равно не получается

Comment: Значит в биос стоит английский

Comment: Это можно как-то исправить?

Comment: Не уверен, но скорее всего вы покупали компьютер за рубежом

Comment: Или можно поменять шрифт. открой свойства cmd и поставь шрифт lucida console

Comment: Попробуй прописать в начале main     SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);